# What is the difference between using "-ne" and "!=" for evaluating the exit code in KornShell (ksh)?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

What is the difference between the following two KornShell (ksh) snippets because they both behave exactly the same *thus far* during testing? The return code (e.g., exit code, return status, exit status, returnCode) is from a SQL*Plus command if that matters.

**kornShellSnippet1.ksh**

```
returnCode=${?}
    if [[ ${returnCode} -ne 0 ]]; then #successful command returns 0#
```

**kornShellSnippet2.ksh**

```
returnCode=${?}
    if [[ ${returnCode} != 0 ]]; then #successful command returns 0#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-ne` is a numeric test, `!=` is a string test. Since you know `$?` is a number, it makes sense to use the numeric test.

Comment: Is there any command I can run in ksh that will tell me what datatype a variable is? I want to run this on ${?} and hopefully it says a number.

Comment: This is confusing to me because I thought that shell variables have no type.

Comment: @javaPlease42  `$?` always contains a number.  In ksh93, variables can actually be defined as integers or floats. It is always safe to use those in numeric operations.  If a variable has no predefined type, it will be treated as a string; note that strings can still contain numbers, and in that case it can still be used as such.  However, ksh will fail with a fatal error if a number is not properly formatted.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld So it would be safer to use `!=` in ksh for testing `${?}`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `-ne` is legacy syntax supported for backward compatibility, while (within ksh double square brackets at least) `!=` etc are the native ksh syntax.

For comparing numbers though, wouldn't you use the arithmetic syntax?

```
let returnCode=${?}

if (( returnCode != 0 )); then #successful command returns 0#
```